# The layout of the index and CRUD pages are from right to left instead of left to right in Easyadmin using Symfony framework

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

When I log on to easyadmin everything seems normal like this.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klql3.png)

But once I refresh the page everything looks likes it's on the opposite direction it is supposed to be like this.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgQBS.png)

The code I have is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Post;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Router\CrudUrlGenerator;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $routeBuilder = $this->get(CrudUrlGenerator::class)->build();

        return $this->redirect($routeBuilder->setController(PostCrudController::class)->generateUrl());
    }

    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('Dashboard');
    }

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Nieuws', 'far fa-newspaper', Post::class);
    }
}
```

In the CRUD pages the same problem persists.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I fixed it by adding  `->setTextDirection('ltr');` to the configureDashboard like this:

```
public function configureDashboard() : Dashboard
{
    return Dashboard::new()
        ->setTitle('Dashboard')
        ->setTextDirection('ltr');
}
```